# How can I make $routeProvider to work properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, configuration, angularjs-ng-route

I'm trying to build a shell manually trying to figure out how it works

Structure:

```
- application(php stuff)

- webroot
-- app
--- app.js

-- templates
--- main
---- login
----- login.html

index.html (with angularjs libs)
```

app.js:

```
function config($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/login",{
            templateUrl: "../templates/main/login/login.html"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo:"/other" });
}


angular
    .module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])
    .config(config);
```

login:

```
<div>LOGIN test template</div>
```

"/other" doesn't exit.
Besides I tried different pathes as:
templateUrl: "templates/main/login/login.html"
templateUrl: "webroot/templates/main/login/login.html"

By the way the url comes with an "#" (eg. nameDomain.com/#/login, but it should be nameDomain.com/#login) but angularjs seems allow only /nameUrlTemplate

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Angular's docs for [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), as this should clear up some of your confusion.

I think what you want to do here is use an existing route in your `.otherwise`, because since `/other` isn't defined anywhere, Angular won't know what do you with it:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
app.config(function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/main/index.html'
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/main/login/login.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

I believe this should give you the effect you're looking for. Obviously you can tweak it as you see fit, if for example you wanted to have a 404 route/template for anything that you don't define. As it stands, this will always fall back to the homepage for a particular route that doesn't exist. This gets more complicated when you're considering users and logged in/out states, but this is more of a proof-of-concept.

Additionally, `ngRoute` will render by default a URL in the format of `/#/foo` since that is using a hashbang-style format, which enables crawlers for search engines to be able to parse and read the various pages/states of a JavaScript webpp. What you're referring to is a document fragment, which are **not** indexable by crawlers. You can read more about the differences on Google's [Webmaster docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification).

Comment: What's wrong with my WHEN .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: '../templates/main/login/login.html'
        })

Comment: additionally: I'd like to have /#login instead /#/login